# Building the Spock tutorial example fails

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack, haskell-spock

I wanted to get going with Haskell a little bit and therefore took a look at the Spock framework. To start clean, I uninstalled everything Haskell related from my Arch Linux machine and installed ghcup, Cabal and Stack using the install scripts from their respective websites.

Now I want to follow [Spock's Tutorial](https://www.spock.li/tutorials/getting-started). Trying to install Spock globally with `cabal install Spock` as suggested gives me an error (abbreviated):

```
src/Web/Spock/Internal/Wire.hs:43:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘Web.Routing.AbstractRouter’
    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.
   |
43 | import Web.Routing.AbstractRouter
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
cabal: Failed to build Spock-0.9.0.1. See the build log above for details.
```

I already found a question on [reddit on the topic](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/cs5sc3/build_error_when_trying_haskell_spock_tutorial/), but the solution does not apply because I'm not trying to use a specific version of the libraries as implied.

So I try to follow along and build only locally.
But when I reach the point where it says `stack build --fast --pedantic`, the build plan can not be constructed and Stack suggests to add another dependency, `stm-containers`. Doing so, I am presented with two additional suggestions for `focus` and `primitive`. When I add these, the plan fails again, this time without a simple solution:

```
In the dependencies for primitive-0.6.4.0:
    base-4.13.0.0 from stack configuration does not match >=4.5 && <4.13  (latest matching version is 4.12.0.0)
needed due to Spock-example-0.1.0.0 -> primitive-0.6.4.0
```

I can do a little thing with Haskell, but with the build system(s), I am way out of my comfort zone. Help and hints appreciated. Oh, and all versions of course are the latest by the time of this post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to incompatible versions of dependencies, *Spock* won't build with GHC 8.8 and above. A similar problem is described in [Spock issue #149](https://github.com/agrafix/Spock/issues/149), though I'm not fully sure it is exactly the same incompatibility. The error you got from Stack hints at that, as `base-4.13.0.0` is the version of *base* that is bundled with GHC 8.8. cabal-install failed in a more obscure way because, upon noting the incompatibility, it tries to solve the dependencies using older versions of *Spock*, eventually picking 0.9.0.1, attempting and, thanks to a missing version upper bound for the *reroute* dependency, failing to build it.

(Shortly after this answer was posted, the missing upper bound [was retrofitted to the old *Spock* version](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Spock-0.9.0.1/revisions/), so attempting to reproduce the problem now will lead to an easier to understand failure.)

Casting the tutorial aside, the most straightforward way to use Spock given those complications is probably through cabal-install 3+. Begin by using ghcup to switch to GHC 8.6.5:

```
$ ghcup install 8.6.5
$ ghcup set 8.6.5
```

Then, create a blank project with cabal-install:

```
$ mkdir myproject
$ cd myproject
$ cabal init
```

Add *Spock* to the `build-depends` section of `myproject.cabal`:

```
  build-depends:       base >=4.12 && <4.13
                     , Spock == 0.13.*
```

Finally, you can run:

```
$ cabal build
```

Which will install *Spock* and its dependencies before building the project. (Note that you generally don't need to use `cabal install` to install libraries with cabal-install 3.)

It is presumably possible to make it work with Stack as well, by changing to the `lts-14.27` resolver (the latest one that uses GHC 8.6.5), tracking down all dependency versions that need to be overriden (as you had began to do) and manually adding them to the `extra-deps` of `stack.yaml`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did the trick and I would never have figured this out myself!

Comment: Fwiw, the missing version bounds were put in place; so now Cabal should fail rather than attempt to build something that's doomed to fail. https://matrix.hackage.haskell.org/package/Spock shows the current situation.

Comment: @hvr That improves things a bit, thanks. Answer updated accordingly.